# Archiving of project with a sub-project fails, but normal build works

Tags: ios, xcode, adal

I have a project which uses the ADALiOS project. This project is included in my project, and it works all fine when building to debug on my phone. However, I want to submit the App to the App Store and Archive but I get the following error:

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectX-gperwbbtttggqpcvozenraexrhrx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/projectX\ Dev/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ADALiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/ADALiOS.build/Script-8B19339718BAEDE4008FD93A.sh
    cd "/Users/User/Documents/Xcode development/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/ADALiOS"
    /bin/sh -c \"/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectX-gperwbbtttggqpcvozenraexrhrx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/projectX\ Dev/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ADALiOS.build/Release-iphoneos/ADALiOS.build/Script-8B19339718BAEDE4008FD93A.sh\"

Creating Framework folder structure at /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectX-gperwbbtttggqpcvozenraexrhrx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/projectX Dev/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ADALiOS
Copying public headers from /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectX-gperwbbtttggqpcvozenraexrhrx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/projectX Dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/Headers/ADALiOS/
cp: /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectX-gperwbbtttggqpcvozenraexrhrx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/projectX Dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/Headers/ADALiOS/: No such file or directory
```

I am Archiving using the 'Generic iOS Device' option. I have tried a clean build  followed many hints from other build problems but nothing seems to help.

Any suggestion on what could be wrong?

[EDIT:]
I got a clean version of the ADALiOS git repo and this too builds, but does not achieve with the same problem, so it could be related to the ADALiOS project, even though I do not knowhow and why.